# SQL subquery filters data but conversion to JPA with subquery does not filter

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, subquery

[Tree, Treetag and Tag tables with example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQnwd.png)

A tree belongs to a given farm and each farm has its own set of tags.

Each tree can have zero or multiple tags attached to it.

Same tag can be attached to multiple trees.

DDL -

```
DROP TABLE tree_tag;

DROP TABLE tag;

DROP TABLE tree;

DROP TABLE farm;

CREATE TABLE farm (
    id          VARCHAR2(36 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NULL,
    name        VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);

CREATE TABLE tree (
    id          VARCHAR2(36 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NULL,
    farm_id     VARCHAR2(36 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);

CREATE TABLE tag (
    id          VARCHAR2(36 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    farm_id     VARCHAR2(36 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);

CREATE TABLE tree_tag (
    id         VARCHAR2(36 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    tag_id     VARCHAR2(36 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    tree_id    VARCHAR2(36 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    value      VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NULL,
    properties VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);

ALTER TABLE tag ADD CONSTRAINT unq_tag0 UNIQUE ( farm_id,
                                                 name );

ALTER TABLE tree_tag ADD CONSTRAINT unq_tree_tag0 UNIQUE ( tag_id,
                                                           tree_id );

ALTER TABLE tree ADD CONSTRAINT unq_tree0 UNIQUE ( farm_id,
                                                   name );

ALTER TABLE tag
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tagfarm_id FOREIGN KEY ( farm_id )
        REFERENCES farm ( id )
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE tree_tag
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tree_tagtree_id FOREIGN KEY ( tree_id )
        REFERENCES tree ( id )
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE tree_tag
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tree_tagtag_id FOREIGN KEY ( tag_id )
        REFERENCES tag ( id )
            ON DELETE CASCADE;



INSERT INTO farm (
    id,
    name
) VALUES (
    'farm1',
    'farm 1 is big'
);

INSERT INTO farm (
    id,
    name
) VALUES (
    'farm2',
    'farm 2 is small'
);

INSERT INTO tag (
    id,
    farm_id,
    name
) VALUES (
    'tag11',
    'farm1',
    'juicy'
);

INSERT INTO tag (
    id,
    farm_id,
    name
) VALUES (
    'tag12',
    'farm1',
    'sour'
);

INSERT INTO tag (
    id,
    farm_id,
    name
) VALUES (
    'tag13',
    'farm1',
    'sweet'
);

INSERT INTO tag (
    id,
    farm_id,
    name
) VALUES (
    'tag21',
    'farm2',
    'sour'
);

INSERT INTO tree (
    id,
    farm_id,
    name,
    description
) VALUES (
    'tree11',
    'farm1',
    'apple',
    'used for jam'
);

INSERT INTO tree (
    id,
    farm_id,
    name
) VALUES (
    'tree12',
    'farm1',
    'cherry'
);

INSERT INTO tree (
    id,
    farm_id,
    name
) VALUES (
    'tree13',
    'farm1',
    'plum'
);

INSERT INTO tree (
    id,
    farm_id,
    name
) VALUES (
    'tree21',
    'farm2',
    'apple'
);

INSERT INTO tree_tag (
    id,
    tree_id,
    tag_id
) VALUES (
    '1',
    'tree11',
    'tag12'
);

INSERT INTO tree_tag (
    id,
    tree_id,
    tag_id
) VALUES (
    '2',
    'tree12',
    'tag11'
);

INSERT INTO tree_tag (
    id,
    tree_id,
    tag_id
) VALUES (
    '3',
    'tree12',
    'tag13'
);

INSERT INTO tree_tag (
    id,
    tree_id,
    tag_id
) VALUES (
    '4',
    'tree13',
    'tag12'
);

INSERT INTO tree_tag (
    id,
    tree_id,
    tag_id
) VALUES (
    '5',
    'tree13',
    'tag11'
);
```

Query:

1. *Want to get a list of trees w/o duplicates where either the name
   or the description or the tag name matches the filter in a given
   farm*
2. *Want to get the count of this unique list of trees in a
   given farm*

**This is a paging request so step 1 query will be called multiple times but step 2 query will be executed only once.**

SQL -

This works but when I convert to JPA then subquery is returning all the entries in tree_tag i.e filtering is not happening in JPA subquery

```
SELECT
    t.farm_id,
    t.id,
    t.name,
    t.description
FROM
    tree t
WHERE
        t.farm_id = :farmid
    AND ( lower(t.name) LIKE '%'
                             || lower(:filter)
                             || '%'
          OR lower(t.description) LIKE '%'
                                       || lower(:filter)
                                       || '%'
          OR ( t.id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            tt.tree_id
        FROM
            tree_tag tt, tag      ttag
        WHERE
                tt.tag_id = ttag.id
            AND lower(ttag.name) LIKE '%'
                                      || lower(:filter)
                                      || '%'
    ) ) );

SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    tree t
WHERE
        t.farm_id = :farmid
    AND ( lower(t.name) LIKE '%'
                             || lower(:filter)
                             || '%'
          OR lower(t.description) LIKE '%'
                                       || lower(:filter)
                                       || '%'
          OR ( t.id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            tt.tree_id
        FROM
            tree_tag tt, tag      ttag
        WHERE
                tt.tag_id = ttag.id
            AND lower(ttag.name) LIKE '%'
                                      || lower(:filter)
                                      || '%'
    ) ) );
```

JPA -

```
void buildQuery(EntityManager em, String farmId, String filter) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tree> cq = cb.createQuery(Tree.class);
    Root<Tree> tree = cq.from(Tree.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    predicates.add(cb.equal(tree.get("farm").get("id"), farmId));

    Predicate namePredicate = cb.like(tree.get(Tree_.name), "%"+filter+"%");
    Predicate descriptionPredicate = cb.like(tree.get(Tree_.description), "%"+filter+"%");

    Subquery<String> subQuery = cq.subquery(String.class);
    Root<TreeTag> treeTagRoot = subQuery.from(TreeTag.class);
    Join<TreeTag, Tag> treeTagTagJoin = treeTagRoot.join(TreeTag_.tag);

    List<Predicate> subPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
    subPredicates.add(cb.equal(treeTagRoot.get(TreeTag_.tag).get(Tag_.id), treeTagTagJoin.get(Tag_.id)));
    subPredicates.add(cb.like(treeTagTagJoin.get(Tag_.name), "%"+filter+"%"));

    subQuery.select(treeTagRoot.get(Treetag_.tree).get(Tree_.id)).distinct(true).where(subPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

    Predicate inSubQueryPredicate = tree.get(Tree_.id).in(subQuery);
    predicates.add(cb.or(namePredicate, descriptionPredicate, inSubQueryPredicate));
    

    cq = cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    cq = cq.orderBy(request.buildOrderBy(cb, tree));

    TypedQuery<Tree> query = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<Tree> trees = query.getResultList();

    // for count - using the same query as above but replacing above 2 lines as 
    //    cq = cq.select(cb.count(tree));
    //    TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createQuery(cq);
    //    int count = query.getSingleResult().intValue();

}
```

Entity Classes -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FARM"))
public class Farm {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
String id;

public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TAG", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"FARM_ID", "NAME"}))
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FARM_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    Farm farm;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    protected String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tag", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private List<TreeTag> treeTagList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ResourceTag {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID", nullable = false)
    protected Tag tag;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    protected String value;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TREE_TAG", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"TAG_ID", "TREE_ID"}))
public class TreeTag extends ResourceTag {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TREE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Tree tree;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="TREE",uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"NAME”,"FARM_ID"}))
public class Tree {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FARM_ID", nullable = false)
    Farm farm;

    @Column(name= "NAME",  nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tree", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CascadeOnDelete
    @BatchFetch(value=BatchFetchType.JOIN)
    private List<TreeTag> treeTagList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

How can I make this JPA code work for both the list and count? Thanks

Comment: Please do not post table with data as an image; see [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).  Instead post complete table description (ddl script) and separately the sample data both as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14).

Comment: Show us your java entities

Comment: @grigouille Added entity classes. thx